# медиа-запросы не работает

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня не работает медиа-запросы. Я его поставила в низ. Когда проверяю в styles, то вижу такую фразу *`«unknown property name»`* (неизвестное имя свойства). Как мне сделать чтобы он заработал.

```
/* Media
======================*/

/* Intro*/

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  
    .intro__subtitle {
       font-size: 8px; 
    }
}
```

Comment: В низ чего? Это вопрос про CSS, при чем тут C#?

Comment: Каким образом C# относится к вопросу? Думаю, вам стоит подобрать более подходящие теги.